# CSS border scaling

Tags: css

I have a set of A tags with `display` set to `block`. Each each is specifically has a `border` on the right. They fit perfectly into a container. However, when the page is zoomed out using the browser's zoom control, everything but the borders scale and the layout is broken. Is there a way to fix this?

This behavior can be replicated in Firefox 3.6.10 and Safari 4.

I had never before noticed that the borders do not scale.

Comment: As far as I can determine, borders don't scale. If you check out CNN.com you can confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

try to set the border-with in em instead of px - if your font-size is `12px`, you could write

`border-width: 0.09 em;`

this will be 1px width in normal size, and hopefully it scales correct (can't test it now, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

There are other things that won't scale either -- radio buttons and select boxes are the classic ones, though it does differ between browsers.

Also, you'll get different effects depending on the sizing units you use for your CSS -- ie whether you use `%`, `px` or `em`, etc. Again, this will vary between browsers.

So the bottom line is that using the browser's zoom function is likely to break things on your layout. I honestly wouldn't expect things to be perfect with zoom, nor the same results in different browsers.